# Getting a fixed number of zeroes randomly in a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, random

I have a matrix of size 2000x50. For the 50 places in each of the 2000 rows, I want exactly 6 of them to be 1 and the remaining 44 to be 0. This distribution needs to be random across each row. I have tried using the `sample`, `rbinom` functions but none of them seem to be helping. It is also possible that I might not be using them correctly. All thoughts and inputs regarding this will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Edit- Initially I wanted those 6 numbers to be one but now I want them to be sampled randomly from a gamma distribution with both shape and scale= 4. How do I make changes to the suggestions below to incorporate this? I am very new to R and these basic things seem to be troubling me. Thanks once again.

Comment: Try: `sample(rep(0:1, c(44,6)))`

Comment: and for the matrix `as.matrix(sapply(1:2000, function(x) sample(rep(0:1, c(44,6)))))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will create the object you requested:

```r
do.call("cbind", lapply(1:2000, function(x) sample(c(rep(1, 6), rep(0, 44)))))
```

Comment: I am getting weird [,1914] like outputs for the 2000 entries. Maybe I am missing something. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: It is just because the matrix is too large to print. You get the same thing printed on screen if you do `matrix(rep(0, 1e5), nrow=50)`. But the matrix has the structure you described. Try storing to a variable `x`  and looking at the first column with x[,1].

Comment: @unknown2718 I think you just need to change `sample(c(rep(1, 6), rep(0, 44))` to `sample(c(rgamma(6, 4, 4), rep(0, 44))`

Answer (score 1):

Based on the approach by @Gki in the comments, you can generate a matrix via `replicate` + `t`, i.e.,

```
m <- t(replicate(2000,sample(rep(0:1, c(44,6)))))
```